# how to install opencv_contrib on ubuntu?

Tags: qt, opencv

I got opencv_contrib pack files from github **https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib**
and built it successfully as the README says ,

`$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules ..`

then I typed make install to generate .so files (Did I misunderstand this command here?) .
But when I use qt to compile this example docs.opencv.org/master/db/d56/tutorial_capture_graycode_pattern.html#gsc.tab=0

it comes error like

```
 undefined reference to `cv::structured_light::GrayCodePattern::Params::Params()'
```

[image]

what should I do?

the following things I've added it in .pro

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/tau/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/include                   /home/tau/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules/structured_light/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio-lopencv_structured_light
```

Comment: I solved this problem by deleting all the files in ../build , and rebuild opencv with opencv_contrib, but this is not what I intended,   since it takes much time and I don't know whether it will cause any other problem or not